# ssh remote works from bash command line but not bash script

Tags: ubuntu, command-line, bash, ssh, bash-scripting

#### (Note: Even though I have answered a couple of my own questions, I still have an unanswered question at the bottom of this post.)

When I run the following command from a bash command line it works.

```
ssh -t -v my-rails-project@192.168.29.205 sudo /home/my-rails-project/x/pg_rsync_ralph07_to_ralph12_finish
```

And the ssh verbose output is:

```
OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.4, OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.29.205 [192.168.29.205] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/my-rails-project/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/my-rails-project/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/my-rails-project/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/my-rails-project/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/my-rails-project/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/my-rails-project/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/my-rails-project/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/my-rails-project/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.4
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.4
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.4 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to 192.168.29.205:22 as 'my-rails-project'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:EnDsn2kFQgiA56e4B2UuvDr3ajTLlN7/15lxLItnjUQ
debug1: Host '192.168.29.205' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/my-rails-project/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/my-rails-project/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg rsa-sha2-512 blen 279
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to 192.168.29.205 ([192.168.29.205]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
debug1: client_input_global_request: rtype hostkeys-00@openssh.com want_reply 0
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: Sending env LANG = en_US.UTF-8
debug1: Sending command: sudo /home/my-rails-project/x/pg_rsync_ralph07_to_ralph12_finish
```

The exact same line is in a bash script and I get

```
OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.4, OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.29.205 [192.168.29.205] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: permanently_set_uid: 0/0
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.4
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.4
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.4 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to 192.168.29.205:22 as 'my-rails-project'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:EnDsn2kFQgiA56e4B2UuvDr3ajTLlN7/15lxLItnjUQ
debug1: Host '192.168.29.205' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /root/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

The two outputs diverge at the line
(script)

```
debug1: Found key in /root/.ssh/known_hosts:1
```

(command line)

```
debug1: Found key in /home/my-rails-project/.ssh/known_hosts:1
```

I don't know if that divergence points to the problem.

So my question is:

Why is ssh looking at /root/.ssh/known_hosts when running from a script and looking at /home/my-rails-project/.ssh/known_hosts when run from the command line?

### Answering my own question immediately above:

Ok, as I was writing this up the answer for the divergence became clear: I was running the script as

```
sudo myScript
```

So my further question is: How do I tell ssh to use /home/my-rails-project/.ssh/known_hosts for known_hosts?

### Answering my own question immediately above

A bit of research led me to the answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10765946/ssh-use-known-hosts-other-than-home-ssh-known-hosts

So now my command line now looks like

```
ssh -o UserKnownHostsFile=/home/my-rails-project/.ssh/known_hosts -t -v my-rails-project@192.168.29.205 sudo /home/my-rails-project/x/pg_rsync_ralph07_to_ralph12_finish
```

The command line immediately above again works when I do not have a sudo in front of it.  It fails when I use a sudo in front of it.  The verbose output is:

```
my-rails-project@my-rails-project:~$ sudo ssh -o UserKnownHostsFile=/home/my-rails-project/.ssh/known_hosts -t -v my-rails-project@192.168.29.205 sudo /home/my-rails-project/x/pg_rsync_ralph07_to_ralph12_finish
[sudo] password for my-rails-project: 
OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.4, OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.29.205 [192.168.29.205] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: permanently_set_uid: 0/0
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.4
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.4
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.4 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to 192.168.29.205:22 as 'my-rails-project'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:EnDsn2kFQgiA56e4B2UuvDr3ajTLlN7/15lxLItnjUQ
debug1: Host '192.168.29.205' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/my-rails-project/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
my-rails-project@my-rails-project:~$
```

And the sudo and non-sudo verbose outputs diverge near the end of the verbose listing near

```
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
my-rails-project@my-rails-project:~$
```

### Question:

How do I tell ssh to use /home/my-rails-project/.ssh instead of /root/.ssh for my private key and still be sudo on the target system?

### Answering my own question immediately above:

Looking at http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/ssh.1.html

So now the ssh command line is (adding a **-i** option)

```
ssh -o UserKnownHostsFile=/home/my-rails-project/.ssh/known_hosts -i /home/my-rails-project/.ssh/id_rsa -t -v my-rails-project@192.168.29.205 sudo /home/my-rails-project/x/pg_rsync_ralph07_to_ralph12_finish
```

And then I have success except something (ssh?) is asking for a password.  The output now looks like:

```
my-rails-project@my-rails-project:~$ sudo ssh -o UserKnownHostsFile=/home/my-rails-project/.ssh/known_hosts -i /home/my-rails-project/.ssh/id_rsa -t -v my-rails-project@192.168.29.205 sudo /home/my-rails-project/x/pg_rsync_ralph07_to_ralph12_finish
OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.4, OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.29.205 [192.168.29.205] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: permanently_set_uid: 0/0
debug1: identity file /home/my-rails-project/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/my-rails-project/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.4
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.4
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.4 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to 192.168.29.205:22 as 'my-rails-project'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:EnDsn2kFQgiA56e4B2UuvDr3ajTLlN7/15lxLItnjUQ
debug1: Host '192.168.29.205' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/my-rails-project/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/my-rails-project/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg rsa-sha2-512 blen 279
Enter passphrase for key '/home/my-rails-project/.ssh/id_rsa': 
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to 192.168.29.205 ([192.168.29.205]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
debug1: client_input_global_request: rtype hostkeys-00@openssh.com want_reply 0
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: Sending env LANG = en_US.UTF-8
debug1: Sending command: sudo /home/my-rails-project/x/pg_rsync_ralph07_to_ralph12_finish
```

### Question:

I get the following prompt:

```
Enter passphrase for key '/home/my-rails-project/.ssh/id_rsa':
```

**How do I suppress this request for a password?**

I have managed to suppress most of the requests for passwords by massaging /etc/sudoers.d/ralph on both my machines (Ralph07 and Ralph12)

```
# This script should only be run on Ralph07
my-rails-project ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD: /home/my-rails-project/x/pg_rsync_ralph07_to_ralph12

# This script should only be run on Ralph12
my-rails-project ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD: /home/my-rails-project/x/pg_rsync_ralph07_to_ralph12_finish
```

Answer (score 1):

The 'Enter passphrase for key' prompt is displayed because your ssh key was created with a passphrase.

You can remove the passphrase from your ssh key with the following:

```
ssh-keygen -p -N '' -f ~/my-rails-project/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Or you can create a new key without a passphrase:

```
ssh-keygen -q -t rsa -b 4096 -N '' -C '' -f ~/my-rails-project/.ssh/id_rsa
```

You can also take a look at the `sshpass` tool which can be used to supply passphrases for ssh commands but it is not recommended as it opens up some security issues.

Comment: Oh wow!  Thanks!

I wish I had 15+ reputation points so I could up vote your answer.